# Workaround for the ? of sqlite3.Cursor instance

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.7

I have a table with 16 columns and I would like to replace the syntax of the [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) method, which is:

```
# DATABASE is of type sqlite3.Cursor 
# data is of type List[List]
DATABASE.executemany(
          "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", data
                      )
DATABASE_CONNECTION.commit()
```

with something more compact. I don't want to repeat the question mark 16 times. Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the sql statement lik ethis:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (" + ("?," * len(data)).strip(",") + ")"
```

so that you get `"?,"` repeated as many times as the number of items in `data` and use it:

```
DATABASE.executemany(sql, data)
```

Comment: `",".join("?" * len(data))` would be more succinct.

Comment: @AKX yes, it would be. Also, I learnt a new word today: *succint*.